# html forms to sql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a forms page named "employee.php" for taking in user data. Also I have another file named SQLConnectionProcess.php which contains the code for linking forms in employee.php to sql table. The name of the database is "employee information" and the table's name is "employee info". I am using phpmyadmin and XAMPP for local server testing.

employee.php code:

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="EmployeeDatabase" action="SQLConnectionProcess.php" method="post">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

<h1>EMPLOYEE DATABASE</h1>

Employe Card NO: <input type="text" name="cardNO" ><br><br>
Employee NO: <input type="text" name="employeeNO" ><br><br>
Employee Name: <input type="text" name="employeename"><br><br>
Nationality: <input type="text" name="nationality"><br><br>
Profession: <input type="text" name="profession"><br><br>
DOB: <input type="text" name="DOB"><br><br>
DOJ: <input type="text" name="DOJ"><br><br>
DOA(VisitVisa): <input type="text" name="DOA"><br><br>
Company Code: <input type="text" name="companycode"><br><br>
Sponsor Code: <input type="text" name="sponsorcode"><br><br>
Visa Type: <input type="text" name="visatype"><br><br>
Status: <input type="text" name="status"><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

SQLConnectionProcess.php code:

```
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){
  $cardNO= isset($_POST['cardNO']) ? $_POST['cardNO'] : 0;
  $employeeNO= isset($_POST['employeeNO']) ? $_POST['employeeNO'] : 0;
  $employeename= isset($_POST['employeename']) ? $_POST['employeename'] : "";
  $nationality= isset($_POST['nationality']) ? $_POST['nationality'] : "";
  $profession= isset($_POST['profession']) ? $_POST['profession'] : "";
  $DOB= isset($_POST['DOB']) ? $_POST['DOB'] : "";
  $DOJ= isset($_POST['DOJ']) ? $_POST['DOJ'] : "";
  $DOA= isset($_POST['DOA']) ? $_POST['DOA'] : "";
  $companycode = isset($_POST['companycode']) ? $_POST['companycode'] : 0;
  $sponsorcode= isset($_POST['sponsorcode']) ? $_POST['sponsorcode'] : 0;
  $visatype= isset($_POST['visatype']) ? $_POST['visatype'] : "";
  $status= isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : "";
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','employee information');
  $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO table_employee info(Employee Card NO,Employee NO,Employee Name,Nationality,Profession,DOB,DOJ,DOA(VisitVisa),Company Code,Sponsor Code,Visa Type,Status) VALUES ('','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",$cardNO,$employeeNO,$employeename,$nationality,$profession,$DOB,$DOJ,$DOA,$companycode,$sponsorcode,$visatype,$status);
  mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
?>
```

But when I submit my forms from employee.php I get the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: emplo‌​yeeNO in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: sponsor‌​code in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 16

I am unable to find the source of the errors. Kindly help me

Comment: Did you enter data for emplo‌​yeeNO & sponsorcode?

Comment: yeah, try to submit your form by entering all the data, if you receives it make some validation at your client end. Secondly, try to debug the problem and use `var_dump($_POST);exit;` to see what's coming in the post request.

Comment: I tried entering data in all the forms. Same errors persist...

Comment: See my edited code again. I am now just getting a white screen

Comment: yes because you have not echo anywhere in your code. Please check your query data will be inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isset()` to prevent from above error.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){
  $cardNO= isset($_POST['cardNO']) ? $_POST['cardNO'] : 0;
  $employeeNO= isset($_POST['employeeNO']) ? $_POST['employeeNO'] : 0;
  $employeename= isset($_POST['employeename']) ? $_POST['employeename'] : "";
  $nationality= isset($_POST['nationality']) ? $_POST['nationality'] : "";
  $profession= isset($_POST['profession']) ? $_POST['profession'] : "";
  $DOB= isset($_POST['DOB']) ? $_POST['DOB'] : "";
  $DOJ= isset($_POST['DOJ']) ? $_POST['DOJ'] : "";
  $DOA= isset($_POST['DOA']) ? $_POST['DOA'] : "";
  $companycode = isset($_POST['companycode']) ? $_POST['companycode'] : 0;
  $sponsorcode= isset($_POST['sponsorcode']) ? $_POST['sponsorcode'] : 0;
  $visatype= isset($_POST['visatype']) ? $_POST['visatype'] : "";
  $status= isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : "";
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','employee information');
  $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO employee_info info(EmployeeCardNO,EmployeeNO,EmployeeName,Nationality,Profession,DOB,DOJ,DOA(VisitVisa),CompanyCode,SponsorCode,VisaType,Status) VALUES ('','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",$cardNO,$employeeNO,$employeename,$nationality,$profession,$DOB,$DOJ,$DOA,$companycode,$sponsorcode,$visatype,$status);
  mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the above code. No more errors. Just empty page. does it mean its working?

Comment: I am still learning to use phpmyadmin so I don't know yet if the database is receiving input from forms

Comment: my tables name is "employee info" and database name is "employee information". should I worry about "table_employee info" that we have used in our code. what does table_ do? is it syntax or name given to the table in my code?

Comment: give table name employee_info and remove space from all column names. I have edited sprintf line use that after doing changes in phpmyadmin. @Gotham

Comment: we need to use isset() for preventing from above error it will check that data is exist in post or not and if not exist then it will set with null or 0. @SanzeebAryal

Comment: @SanzeebAryal You can also enclose table and column names containing whitespaces within backticks.

Comment: did everything as you mentioned. Should I worry about the folder my sql database and table is saved in? My front end forms page is saved in htdocs folder in XAMPP. Not sure where my database is saved. Any changes required on that front? @ Ruchish

Comment: Just echo your query and take that query from front output and paste it in phpmyadmin sql tab and check record inserted or giving any error. @Gotham

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on data expected from client. First ensure every data read from `$_POST` array is set. If a value is not important you can chose a default value. You can simplify it with a short function

```
function get(&$var, $default = null)
{
  return isset($var) ? $var : $default;
}

$cardNO = get($_POST['cardNO'], 0);
```

If a required input is not present, you have to notify the user instead.

Then never ever mix strings coming from unsafe source (e.g. the client) into SQL statements. Use prepared statements instead.

```
$query_string = 'INSERT INTO `tablename` (`fieldname1`, `fieldname2`) VALUES (?,?);';
if($statement =  $mysqli_connection->prepare( $query_string ))
{ $statement->bind_param('s', $variable1);
  $statement->bind_param('s', $variable2);
  $statement->execute();
  // fetch the result...
}
```

For further information see also [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Emulated prepared statements should be turned off by options on connect since otherwise under circumstances encoding attacks are still possible.

If you need to access a database that contains whitespaces in identifiers, you can surround those in backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM `table name with whitespaces`;
```